# How to analyse one level deeper of the default profiling of Joomla?

Tags: performance

I am getting the following results from measuring the performance:

```
Time: 104.01 ms / 104.01 ms Memory: 0.878 MB / 1.11 MB afterLoad
Time: 627.05 ms / 731.05 ms Memory: 4.563 MB / 5.67 MB afterInitialise
```

Any idea what is behind the 627ms? This seems like ages to me.  Why does this take so long?

```
Time: 41.29 ms / 1466.08 ms Memory: 0.000 MB / 11.64 MB afterDispatch
Time: 561.62 ms / 2027.70 ms Memory: 7.045 MB / 18.69 MB beforeRenderModule mod_hd6_customcss (LP-ALL-CustomCSS)
```

Why does this also takes so long to execute?

```
Time: 918.16 ms / 2949.28 ms Memory: 1.473 MB / 20.19 MB Before Access::getAssetRules (id:8 name:com_content)
```

Any idea how to dig down the ages of waiting?

Comment: We cannot possibly know what is specifically causing the perceived lag.  Your question is Unclear because we don't have enough information.  Your question is Too Broad because you are asking multiple distinct questions.  Your question may be generally off-topic if professional hands-on support is required.

Comment: https://www.joomlapolis.com/forum/153-professional-member-support/223859-anything-i-can-do-to-improve-performance https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/improve-speed/

Comment: With Debug ON have you looked at the data base queries in the Console at the bottom to see if there are some relatively high query times?

Comment: @Irata, yes queries are pretty fast (usually below 500ms)